# Does object initiation inside or outside dbcontext using syntax matter in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

As the title says, my code follows.

Team.cs

```
public class Team {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // other props

    public virtual ICollection<TeamPlayer> TeamPlayers { get; set; }
}
```

Player.cs

```
public class Player {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // other props

    public virtual ICollection<TeamPlayer> TeamPlayers { get; set; }
}
```

TeamPlayer.cs

```
public class TeamPlayer {

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    public Skater Player { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }

}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
addTeam(){
    var team = new Team {
        Name = "a team";
        TeamPlayers = new List<TeamPlayer> {
            new TeamPlayer{
                Player = player, // assume player object is not null
                Team = team
            }
        }
    }

    this.addToDB(team);
}

addToDB(Team team) {
    using(var ctx = DBContext()) {
        ctx.Teams.Add(team);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

DatabaseContext.cs (snippets)

```
public class CompetitionContext: DbContext {

    // some code

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
            builder.Entity<TeamPlayer>()
            .HasKey(teamPlayer => new { teamPlayer.PlayerId, teamPlayer.TeamId });
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

If I construct my code as above, every time I save a new team with more than 1 teamPlayers in the List, it shows an exception

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll

Base on the given example in the documentation, the team and teamPlayers should be created

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#adding-a-graph-of-new-entities)

But, if I construct the object inside the using scope, the object is inserted successfully and as expected.

I am wondering why does object initialization position matter whether it is inside or outside using scope?

Comment: Show us your dbcontext.cs

Comment: show more of he construction code.. like `
addToDB(Team team)` where team was created so that it could be passed in, what you trying to do it possible, my guess atm is your misisng the setup of the relationships in onmodelcreation in the dbcontext... where you use fluent snytax to discribe the relationship. but would be nice to see the entire code flow too.

Comment: Let me update my code